# Pagination / Infinite scrolling in Flutter with caching and realtime invalidation

Tags: flutter, caching, pagination, reactive-programming, infinite-scroll

It's been a long time since I started to search for a Flutter ListView library that will allow me to use pagination in a smart way. Sadly I haven't found anything that meets my criteria:

1. **Smart pagination**: the library should't simply increase a list page-by-page but must have a fixed size cache which load and keep in memory only the needed pages in the moment.
2. **Async loading**: the library should basically accept a function which returns a future of a list representing a page.
3. **Real-time invalidation**: Dart has streams, so somehow the library should use their power to handle invalidation and reload everything needed when data changes in a reactive way.

Basically I wanted something that acted like PagedListAdapter + DataSource.Factory + LiveData in the standard Android library.
I came up with the widget **PagedListView**:

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:fimber/fimber.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

typedef Future<List<T>> PageFuture<T>(int pageIndex);

typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, int index, T entry);
typedef Widget WaitBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget PlaceholderBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget EmptyResultBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget ErrorBuilder(BuildContext context);

class PagedListView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageSize;
  final PageFuture<T> pageFuture;
  final Stream<int> countStream;

  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final WaitBuilder waitBuilder;
  final PlaceholderBuilder placeholderBuilder;
  final EmptyResultBuilder emptyResultBuilder;
  final ErrorBuilder errorBuilder;

  PagedListView(
      {@required this.pageSize,
      @required this.pageFuture,
      @required this.countStream,
      @required this.itemBuilder,
      @required this.waitBuilder,
      @required this.placeholderBuilder,
      @required this.emptyResultBuilder,
      @required this.errorBuilder});

  @override
  _PagedListView<T> createState() => _PagedListView<T>();
}

class _PagedListView<T> extends State<PagedListView<T>> {
  /// Represent the number of cached pages before and after the current page.
  /// If edgeCachePageCount = 1 the total number of cached pages are 3 (one before + current + one after).
  /// TODO calculate from pageSize
  final int edgeCachePageCount = 2;

  int get maxCachedPageCount => (edgeCachePageCount * 2) + 1;

  int currentPage = 0;

  List<T> items;
  Object error;

  int totalCount = -1;

  /// Contains the page indexes which the fetching is started but not completed.
  final progressPages = Set<int>();

  /// Contains the page indexes already retrieved.
  final cachedPages = Set<int>();

  int limitStartIndex = -1;
  int limitEndIndex = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    items = List.filled(widget.pageSize * maxCachedPageCount, null);

    widget.countStream.listen((int count) {
      Fimber.i("Total count changed: $count");
      totalCount = count;

      // Invalidate.
      cachedPages.clear();

      if (count > 0) {
        _fetchPages(PageRequest.SAME);
      }

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  void _fetchPages(PageRequest pageRequest) {
    Set<int> refreshIndexes = _getRefreshIndexes();
    //Fimber.i("Refresh indexes are $refreshIndexes");
    refreshIndexes.forEach((pageIndex) => _fetchPage(pageIndex, pageRequest));
  }

  Set<int> _getRefreshIndexes() {
    return getRefreshIndexes(maxCachedPageCount, edgeCachePageCount, currentPage, widget.pageSize, totalCount);
  }

  _fetchPage(int index, PageRequest request) {
    if (cachedPages.contains(index)) {
      // We already have this page.
      return;
    }
    if (!progressPages.contains(index)) {
      //Fimber.i("Fetch page $index start");
      progressPages.add(index);
      widget.pageFuture(index).asStream().map((list) => PageResult<T>(index, request, list)).listen(_onData, onError: _onError);
    }
  }

  void _onData(PageResult<T> data) {
    if (data.items != null) {
      if (!_getRefreshIndexes().contains(data.index)) {
        progressPages.remove(data.index);
        //Fimber.i("Skipping invalid page ${data.index}, currentPage = $currentPage, refreshIndexes = ${_getRefreshIndexes()}");
        return;
      }
      //Fimber.i("Fetch page ${data.index} end");

      if (cachedPages.length == maxCachedPageCount) {
        // The cached page count is exceeded, remove the smallest / greatest page.
        if (data.request == PageRequest.NEXT) {
          int smallestPage = cachedPages.reduce(min);
          cachedPages.remove(smallestPage);
          //Fimber.i("Smallest page $smallestPage removed");
        } else if (data.request == PageRequest.PREVIOUS) {
          int greatestPage = cachedPages.reduce(max);
          cachedPages.remove(greatestPage);
          //Fimber.i("Greatest page $greatestPage removed");
        } else {
          int smallestPage = cachedPages.reduce(min);
          int greatestPage = cachedPages.reduce(max);
          int smallestPageDistance = currentPage - smallestPage;
          int greatestPageDistance = greatestPage - currentPage;
          if (smallestPageDistance >= greatestPageDistance) {
            //Fimber.i("Smallest page $smallestPage removed, smallestPageDistance = $smallestPageDistance, greatestPageDistance = $greatestPageDistance");
            cachedPages.remove(smallestPage);
          } else {
            //Fimber.i("Greatest page $greatestPage removed, smallestPageDistance = $smallestPageDistance, greatestPageDistance = $greatestPageDistance");
            cachedPages.remove(greatestPage);
          }
        }
      }
      Set<int> tempCachedPages = cachedPages.toSet()..add(data.index);

      // Put the result in the correct position.
      int startIndex = widget.pageSize * (data.index % maxCachedPageCount);
      items.setAll(startIndex, data.items);
      //Fimber.i("Fetch page ${data.index} end, startIndex = $startIndex");

      limitStartIndex = cachedPages.isEmpty ? 0 : tempCachedPages.reduce(min) * widget.pageSize;
      //Fimber.i("limitStartIndex set to $limitStartIndex");

      limitEndIndex = cachedPages.isEmpty ? -1 : (widget.pageSize * tempCachedPages.reduce(max)) + data.items.length - 1;
      //Fimber.i("limitEndIndex set to $limitEndIndex");

      cachedPages.add(data.index);
      progressPages.remove(data.index);
      //Fimber.i("Fetch page ${data.index} end, startIndex = $startIndex, cached pages ${cachedPages.toList()..sort()}, currentPage = $currentPage");

      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  void _onError(error) {
    this.error = error;
    setState(() {});
  }

  _fetchNewPage(int index) {
    int newPage = index ~/ widget.pageSize;
    PageRequest pageRequest = newPage > currentPage ? PageRequest.NEXT : (newPage < currentPage ? PageRequest.PREVIOUS : PageRequest.SAME);
    /*pageRequest == PageRequest.NEXT
        ? Fimber.i("Fetch next page $newPage")
        : (pageRequest == PageRequest.PREVIOUS ? Fimber.i("Fetch previous page $newPage") : null);*/
    currentPage = newPage;
    _fetchPages(pageRequest);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (error != null) {
      return widget.errorBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == -1) {
      return widget.waitBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == 0) {
      return widget.emptyResultBuilder(context);
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      key: Key("listView"),
      itemCount: totalCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        if (index < limitStartIndex || index > limitEndIndex) {
          _fetchNewPage(index);
        }
        return _getListItem(context, index);
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _getListItem(BuildContext context, int realIndex) {
    int pageIndex = realIndex ~/ widget.pageSize;
    if (!cachedPages.contains(pageIndex)) {
      return widget.placeholderBuilder(context);
    }
    int cachePageIndex = pageIndex % maxCachedPageCount;
    int cacheIndex = (cachePageIndex * widget.pageSize) + (realIndex % widget.pageSize);
    return widget.itemBuilder(context, realIndex, items[cacheIndex]);
  }
}

enum PageRequest { NEXT, PREVIOUS, SAME }

class PageResult<T> {
  /// Page index of this data.
  final int index;

  /// Represent the direction from the current page when the request was made.
  final PageRequest request;
  final List<T> items;

  PageResult(this.index, this.request, this.items);
}

Set<int> getRefreshIndexes(int maxCachedPageCount, int edgeCachePageCount, int currentPage, int pageSize, int totalCount) {
  List<int> temp = List.generate(min(maxCachedPageCount, (totalCount ~/ pageSize) + 1), (index) => index + (currentPage - edgeCachePageCount));
  int minIndex = temp.reduce(min);
  if (minIndex < 0) {
    return temp.map((index) => index + minIndex.abs()).toSet();
  }
  int maxIndex = temp.reduce(max);
  int maxPage = totalCount ~/ pageSize;
  if (maxIndex > maxPage) {
    return temp.map((index) => index - (maxIndex - maxPage)).toSet();
  }
  return temp.toSet();
}
```

Since I need to know the total amount of items and handle invalidation I figured to accept a `Stream<int>` which returns the real list size every time data is modified.

This is an example of how it's used:

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final MyDatabase database = MyDatabase();

  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  Random random = Random.secure();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Test"),
    ),
    body: PagedListView(
    pageSize: 10,
    pageFuture: (pageIndex) =>
      Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: (random.nextDouble() * 5000).toInt()), () => database.getCategories(10, 10 * pageIndex)),
    countStream: database.countCategories().watchSingle(),
    itemBuilder: _itemBuilder,
    waitBuilder: _waitBuilder,
    placeholderBuilder: _placeholderBuilder,
    emptyResultBuilder: _emptyResultBuilder,
    errorBuilder: _errorBuilder,
    ),
  );
  }

  Widget _itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index, Category item) => Container(
    height: 60,
    child: Center(
      child: ListTile(
      key: Key(item.id.toString()),
      title: Text(item.description),
      subtitle: Text("id = ${item.id}, index = $index")
      ),
    ),
    );

  Widget _waitBuilder(BuildContext context) => Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());

  Widget _placeholderBuilder(BuildContext context) => Container(
    height: 60,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    ));

  Widget _emptyResultBuilder(BuildContext context) => Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Center(
    child: Text("Empty"),
    ));

  Widget _errorBuilder(BuildContext context) => Container(
    color: Colors.red,
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Center(
    child: Text("Error"),
    ));
}
```

I'm using SQLite with Moor to retrieve data (https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/).

- `database.getCategories(10, 10 * pageIndex))` is a method returning the `Future<List<Category>>` representing a page
- `database.countCategories().watchSingle()` is the Stream emitting the list size at every add/update/delete

What do you think?
Am I missing some bugs? Would you done things differently? Maybe in a more simple / elegant / performant way?

Thanks

**UPDATE #1**

I made a new version based on pskink [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074466/pagination-infinite-scrolling-in-flutter-with-caching-and-realtime-invalidatio#comment106248128_60074466) using LruMap.

```dart
import 'package:fimber/fimber.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiver/cache.dart';
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

typedef Future<List<T>> PageFuture<T>(int pageIndex);

typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, int index, T entry);
typedef Widget WaitBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget PlaceholderBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget EmptyResultBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget ErrorBuilder(BuildContext context);

class LazyListView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageSize;
  final PageFuture<T> pageFuture;
  final Stream<int> countStream;

  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final WaitBuilder waitBuilder;
  final PlaceholderBuilder placeholderBuilder;
  final EmptyResultBuilder emptyResultBuilder;
  final ErrorBuilder errorBuilder;

  LazyListView(
      {@required this.pageSize,
      @required this.pageFuture,
      @required this.countStream,
      @required this.itemBuilder,
      @required this.waitBuilder,
      @required this.placeholderBuilder,
      @required this.emptyResultBuilder,
      @required this.errorBuilder});

  @override
  _LazyListView<T> createState() => _LazyListView<T>();
}

class _LazyListView<T> extends State<LazyListView<T>> {
  Map<int, PageResult<T>> map;
  MapCache<int, PageResult<T>> cache;

  Object error;

  int totalCount = -1;

  int currentPage = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    map = LruMap<int, PageResult<T>>(maximumSize: 500 ~/ widget.pageSize);
    cache = MapCache<int, PageResult<T>>(map: map);

    widget.countStream.listen((int count) {
      Fimber.i("Total count changed: $count");
      totalCount = count;

      map.clear();

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (error != null) {
      return widget.errorBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == -1) {
      return widget.waitBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == 0) {
      return widget.emptyResultBuilder(context);
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      key: Key("listView"),
      itemCount: totalCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        currentPage = index ~/ widget.pageSize;
        final pageResult = map[currentPage];
        final value = pageResult == null ? null : pageResult.items[index % widget.pageSize];
        final loading = (value == null);
        if (loading) {
          cache.get(currentPage, ifAbsent: _loadPage).then(reload);
          return widget.placeholderBuilder(context);
        }
        return widget.itemBuilder(context, index, value);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<PageResult<T>> _loadPage(int index) {
    Fimber.i("Start fetch page $index");
    return widget.pageFuture(index).then((list) => PageResult(index, list));
  }

  reload(PageResult<T> value) {
    // Avoid calling setState if it's not needed.
    if ((value.index - currentPage).abs() > 2) {
      // ATTENTION: 2 is an arbitrary value, the distance between the current page and the page in the future result should ensure correct refreshing.
      // It should be greater if item widgets have a smaller height, can be smaller if item widgets have a greater height.
      // TODO: make it configurable?
      Fimber.i("Skipping refreshing for result of page ${value.index}, currentPage = $currentPage");
      return;
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class PageResult<T> {
  /// Page index of this data.
  final int index;

  final List<T> items;

  PageResult(this.index, this.items);
}
```

**UPDATE #2** based on pskink new [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60074466/pagination-infinite-scrolling-in-flutter-with-caching-and-realtime-invalidatio#comment106262878_60074466)

```dart
import 'package:fimber/fimber.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:quiver/cache.dart';
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

typedef Future<List<T>> PageFuture<T>(int pageIndex);

typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, int index, T entry);
typedef Widget WaitBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget PlaceholderBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget EmptyResultBuilder(BuildContext context);
typedef Widget ErrorBuilder(BuildContext context);

class LazyListView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageSize;
  final PageFuture<T> pageFuture;
  final Stream<int> countStream;

  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final WaitBuilder waitBuilder;
  final PlaceholderBuilder placeholderBuilder;
  final EmptyResultBuilder emptyResultBuilder;
  final ErrorBuilder errorBuilder;

  LazyListView(
      {@required this.pageSize,
      @required this.pageFuture,
      @required this.countStream,
      @required this.itemBuilder,
      @required this.waitBuilder,
      @required this.placeholderBuilder,
      @required this.emptyResultBuilder,
      @required this.errorBuilder});

  @override
  _LazyListView<T> createState() => _LazyListView<T>();
}

class _LazyListView<T> extends State<LazyListView<T>> {
  Map<int, PageResult<T>> map;
  MapCache<int, PageResult<T>> cache;

  Object error;

  int totalCount = -1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    map = LruMap<int, PageResult<T>>(maximumSize: 50 ~/ widget.pageSize);
    cache = MapCache<int, PageResult<T>>(map: map);

    widget.countStream.listen((int count) {
      Fimber.i("Total count changed: $count");
      totalCount = count;

      map.clear();

      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (error != null) {
      return widget.errorBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == -1) {
      return widget.waitBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == 0) {
      return widget.emptyResultBuilder(context);
    }
    return ListView.builder(
      key: Key("listView"),
      itemCount: totalCount,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        int currentPage = index ~/ widget.pageSize;
        final pageResult = map[currentPage];
        final value = pageResult == null ? null : pageResult.items[index % widget.pageSize];
        final loading = (value == null);
        if (loading) {
          cache.get(currentPage, ifAbsent: _loadPage).then(_reload);
          return widget.placeholderBuilder(context);
        }
        return widget.itemBuilder(context, index, value);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<PageResult<T>> _loadPage(int index) {
    Fimber.i("Start fetch page $index");
    return widget.pageFuture(index).then((list) => PageResult(index, list));
  }

  _reload(PageResult<T> value) {
    if (value.refreshed) {
      // Avoid calling setState if already called.
      Fimber.i("Skipping refreshing for result of page ${value.index}");
      return;
    }
    setState(() {
      value.refreshed = true;
    });
  }
}

class PageResult<T> {
  /// Page index of this data.
  final int index;

  final List<T> items;
  bool refreshed = false;

  PageResult(this.index, this.items);
}
```

What dou you think?

Comment: see https://gist.github.com/pskink/c9bbe21c68efb14eb1c01ba0a4d93414

Comment: thanks @pskink, using a LruMap should be an improvement but you're not handling reactiveness

Comment: reactiveness? what you mean by that? check [loadIfAbsent](https://gist.github.com/pskink/c9bbe21c68efb14eb1c01ba0a4d93414#file-lazy_list-dart-L45) - this is a method for lazy data loading which returns a `Future` - in this particular case each item = one `Future` but of course in real world it should be paged so for example 10 items = one `Future`

Comment: I mean that in your example cache invalidation is not considered. There isn't a callback on any sort that says "data must be refreshed"

Comment: `map[some_index] = null; setState(() {});`

Comment: i meant `cache.invalidate(key)`,  `map[key] = null` is not enough

Comment: I posted a new version using LruMap and I used ```map.clear()``` when the count stream emits a new value since every item could be changed.

Comment: i would change `reload` method: `if (value.setStateCalled) return; else {setState(() {}); value.setStateCalled = true;}`

Comment: Maybe I don't understand but in this way you're not avoiding to call ```setState``` when the page that completes is not visible.

Comment: recently i found one nice method: `Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext` so try to change your code with: `if (loading) {
          if (!Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext(context)) {
            cache.get(currentPage, ifAbsent: _loadPage).then(reload);
          }
          return widget.placeholderBuilder(context);
        }` - there is one `if` added to skip loding then scrollable scrolls fast - it kind of works (though its a bit strange i confess...) but i did not time to test it much

Comment: but because default implementation of `Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext` is a bit too simple it is better to create a custom `ScrollPhysics` and override its `recommendDeferredLoading` method

Comment: I'm gonna look into ```ScrollPhysics``` as soon as I get the change! Thanks! Do you have any more specific suggestions?

Comment: *"Do you have any more specific suggestions?"*, summarized here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/bZpXwbh9ss/ you can control when then pages load by changing `_LazyListViewPhysics(velocityThreshold: 100)`

Comment: seems that there were dozens of unwanted `scheduleFrameCallback` calls, with `_frameCallbackInProgress` flag there is only one now, see https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/BDpVkDkVJw/ and check the logs while flinging the list

Comment: I've tried and seems to work. Is there a way I can talk to you in private?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the last version thanks to some very useful suggestions

```dart
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:quiver/cache.dart';
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

typedef Future<List<T>> PageFuture<T>(int pageIndex);

typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, int index, T entry);
typedef Widget ErrorBuilder(BuildContext context, dynamic error);

class LazyListView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageSize;
  final PageFuture<T> pageFuture;
  final Stream<int> countStream;

  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder placeholderBuilder;
  final WidgetBuilder waitBuilder;
  final WidgetBuilder emptyResultBuilder;
  final ErrorBuilder errorBuilder;
  final double velocityThreshold;

  LazyListView({
    @required this.pageSize,
    @required this.pageFuture,
    @required this.countStream,
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    @required this.placeholderBuilder,
    this.waitBuilder,
    this.emptyResultBuilder,
    this.errorBuilder,
    this.velocityThreshold = 128,
  })  : assert(pageSize > 0),
        assert(pageFuture != null),
        assert(countStream != null),
        assert(itemBuilder != null),
        assert(placeholderBuilder != null),
        assert(velocityThreshold >= 0);

  @override
  _LazyListViewState<T> createState() => _LazyListViewState<T>();
}

class _LazyListViewState<T> extends State<LazyListView<T>> {
  Map<int, PageResult<T>> map;
  MapCache<int, PageResult<T>> cache;
  dynamic error;
  int totalCount = -1;
  bool _frameCallbackInProgress = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initCache();

    widget.countStream.listen((int count) {
      totalCount = count;
      _initCache();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //debugPrintBeginFrameBanner = true;
    //debugPrintEndFrameBanner = true;
    //print('build');
    if (error != null && widget.errorBuilder != null) return widget.errorBuilder(context, error);
    if (totalCount == -1 && widget.waitBuilder != null) return widget.waitBuilder(context);
    if (totalCount == 0 && widget.emptyResultBuilder != null) return widget.emptyResultBuilder(context);

    return ListView.builder(
      physics: _LazyListViewPhysics(velocityThreshold: widget.velocityThreshold),
      itemCount: max(totalCount, 0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // print('builder $index');
        var page = index ~/ widget.pageSize;
        final pageResult = map[page];
        final value = pageResult?.items?.elementAt(index % widget.pageSize);
        if (value != null) {
          return widget.itemBuilder(context, index, value);
        }

        // print('$index ${Scrollable.of(context).position.activity.velocity}');
        if (!Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext(context)) {
          cache.get(page, ifAbsent: _loadPage).then(_reload).catchError(_error);
        } else if (!_frameCallbackInProgress) {
          _frameCallbackInProgress = true;
          SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback((d) => _deferredReload(context));
        }
        return widget.placeholderBuilder(context, index);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<PageResult<T>> _loadPage(int index) async {
    print('load $index');
    var list = await widget.pageFuture(index);
    return PageResult(index, list);
  }

  void _initCache() {
    map = LruMap<int, PageResult<T>>(maximumSize: 50 ~/ widget.pageSize);
    cache = MapCache<int, PageResult<T>>(map: map);
  }

  void _error(dynamic e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (widget.errorBuilder == null) {
      throw e;
    }
    setState(() => error = e);
  }

  void _reload(PageResult<T> value) => _doReload(value.index);

  void _deferredReload(BuildContext context) {
    print('_deferredReload');
    if (!Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext(context)) {
      _frameCallbackInProgress = false;
      _doReload(-1);
    } else {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback((d) => _deferredReload(context), rescheduling: true);
    }
  }

  void _doReload(int index) {
    // print('reload $index');
    setState(() {});
  }
}

class PageResult<T> {
  /// Page index of this data.
  final int index;
  final List<T> items;

  PageResult(this.index, this.items);
}

class _LazyListViewPhysics extends AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics {
  final double velocityThreshold;

  _LazyListViewPhysics({
    @required this.velocityThreshold,
    ScrollPhysics parent,
  }) : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  recommendDeferredLoading(double velocity, ScrollMetrics metrics, BuildContext context) {
    // print('velocityThreshold: $velocityThreshold');
    return velocity.abs() > velocityThreshold;
  }

  @override
  _LazyListViewPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    // print('applyTo($ancestor)');
    return _LazyListViewPhysics(velocityThreshold: velocityThreshold, parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }
}
```

**UPDATE #1**

This is a new version which ensures futures don't call `setState` if the widget is unmounted.

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'package:quiver/cache.dart';
import 'package:quiver/collection.dart';

typedef Future<List<T>> PageFuture<T>(int pageIndex);

typedef Widget ItemBuilder<T>(BuildContext context, int index, T entry);
typedef Widget ErrorBuilder(BuildContext context, dynamic error);

class LazyListView<T> extends StatefulWidget {
  final int pageSize;
  final PageFuture<T> pageFuture;
  final Stream<int> countStream;

  final ItemBuilder<T> itemBuilder;
  final IndexedWidgetBuilder placeholderBuilder;
  final WidgetBuilder waitBuilder;
  final WidgetBuilder emptyResultBuilder;
  final ErrorBuilder errorBuilder;
  final double velocityThreshold;

  LazyListView({
    @required this.pageSize,
    @required this.pageFuture,
    @required this.countStream,
    @required this.itemBuilder,
    @required this.placeholderBuilder,
    this.waitBuilder,
    this.emptyResultBuilder,
    this.errorBuilder,
    this.velocityThreshold = 128,
  })  : assert(pageSize > 0),
        assert(pageFuture != null),
        assert(countStream != null),
        assert(itemBuilder != null),
        assert(placeholderBuilder != null),
        assert(velocityThreshold >= 0);

  @override
  _LazyListViewState<T> createState() => _LazyListViewState<T>();
}

class _LazyListViewState<T> extends State<LazyListView<T>> {
  Map<int, PageResult<T>> map;
  MapCache<int, PageResult<T>> cache;
  dynamic error;
  int totalCount = -1;
  bool _frameCallbackInProgress = false;

  StreamSubscription<int> countStreamSubscription;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initCache();

    countStreamSubscription = widget.countStream.listen((int count) {
      totalCount = count;
      print('totalCount = $totalCount');
      _initCache();
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    countStreamSubscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    //debugPrintBeginFrameBanner = true;
    //debugPrintEndFrameBanner = true;
    //print('build');
    if (error != null && widget.errorBuilder != null) {
      return widget.errorBuilder(context, error);
    }
    if (totalCount == -1 && widget.waitBuilder != null) {
      return widget.waitBuilder(context);
    }
    if (totalCount == 0 && widget.emptyResultBuilder != null) {
      return widget.emptyResultBuilder(context);
    }

    return ListView.builder(
      physics: _LazyListViewPhysics(velocityThreshold: widget.velocityThreshold),
      itemCount: max(totalCount, 0),
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        // print('builder $index');
        final page = index ~/ widget.pageSize;
        final pageResult = map[page];
        final value = pageResult?.items?.elementAt(index % widget.pageSize);
        if (value != null) {
          return widget.itemBuilder(context, index, value);
        }

        // print('$index ${Scrollable.of(context).position.activity.velocity}');
        if (!Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext(context)) {
          cache.get(page, ifAbsent: _loadPage).then(_reload).catchError(_error);
        } else if (!_frameCallbackInProgress) {
          _frameCallbackInProgress = true;
          SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback((d) => _deferredReload(context));
        }
        return widget.placeholderBuilder(context, index);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<PageResult<T>> _loadPage(int index) async {
    print('load $index');
    var list = await widget.pageFuture(index);
    return PageResult(index, list);
  }

  void _initCache() {
    map = LruMap<int, PageResult<T>>(maximumSize: 512 ~/ widget.pageSize);
    cache = MapCache<int, PageResult<T>>(map: map);
  }

  void _error(dynamic e, StackTrace stackTrace) {
    if (widget.errorBuilder == null) {
      throw e;
    }
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() => error = e);
    }
  }

  void _reload(PageResult<T> value) => _doReload(value.index);

  void _deferredReload(BuildContext context) {
    print('_deferredReload');
    if (!Scrollable.recommendDeferredLoadingForContext(context)) {
      _frameCallbackInProgress = false;
      _doReload(-1);
    } else {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.scheduleFrameCallback((d) => _deferredReload(context), rescheduling: true);
    }
  }

  void _doReload(int index) {
    print('reload $index');
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
}

class PageResult<T> {
  /// Page index of this data.
  final int index;
  final List<T> items;

  PageResult(this.index, this.items);
}

class _LazyListViewPhysics extends AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics {
  final double velocityThreshold;

  _LazyListViewPhysics({
    @required this.velocityThreshold,
    ScrollPhysics parent,
  }) : super(parent: parent);

  @override
  recommendDeferredLoading(double velocity, ScrollMetrics metrics, BuildContext context) {
    // print('velocityThreshold: $velocityThreshold');
    return velocity.abs() > velocityThreshold;
  }

  @override
  _LazyListViewPhysics applyTo(ScrollPhysics ancestor) {
    // print('applyTo($ancestor)');
    return _LazyListViewPhysics(velocityThreshold: velocityThreshold, parent: buildParent(ancestor));
  }
}
```

Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: `recommendDeferredLoading` doesn't override anything and `recommendDeferredLoadingForContext` doesn't exist anymore. Do you have an updated version of your solution? Thanks

Comment: Hi @unveloper, There is other important feature in paging system in android, "Boundaries Callbacks" after you rich DB boundaries. this functionalities will help developers to fetch more data from server if needed.

Comment: I love it. 1) Make it into a regular plugin on pub.dev, it will be much more discoverable than here. 2) Add a simple check to see if `placeholderBuilder` gets a height of zero (like returning a simple `Container()` there, something probably everybody would commit first). With zero height, it will start filling up everything up front.

Comment: I took the liberty of turning it into a package, `huge_listview` for Flutter, with due credit to you as the original idea and originator behind it.