# Flutter | Use Listview.builder inside ListView - Make whole page scrollable

Tags: listview, dart, flutter

I want to build a instagram-like profile page, where all the posts of the current user are listed in a feed. Above that, some information about the user (avatar, follower count, post count, bio, etc.) should be displayed. **The user should be able to scroll the whole page.** At the moment the page can only be scrolled to the height of the sizedBox-widget in my ListView.builder. Just like that:

[image]

The build method of **ProfilePage** class looks like that:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(    
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView(    
          children: <Widget>[
           Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 30.0),
                    child: Text(_user.displayName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.black,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 20.0)),
                  ),
                  ...(all the other information for the "header-part")

                  postImagesWidget(),

            ])));}
```

In **postImagesWidget** I'm using a ListView.builder to build the feed:

```
Widget postImagesWidget(){
return FutureBuilder(
            future: _future,
            builder:
                ((context, AsyncSnapshot<List<DocumentSnapshot>> snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                  return SizedBox(
                    height: 600,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),

                          //shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                          itemBuilder: ((context, index) => ListItem(
                              list: snapshot.data,
                              index: index,
                              user: _user))));
                } else {
                  return Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }),
          );

}
```

I had to add a sizedBox-Widget to avoid this error:

> Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#50ccf NEEDS-PAINT

The description of this error says that I should add shrinkwrap to my ListView.builder, but this crashes my whole app after some scrolling with this error:

> Failed assertion: line 470 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.

**How can I make the whole page scrollable and not the two parts (header & feed) separately?**

I know that i has something to do with the fact, that I am using a ListView.builder inside a ListView...

Best Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `ListView` is not the right widget for the job at hand. What you want to do is display multiple widgets above each other, which a `Column` is designed to do.
So, instead of using the inner `ListView`, consider using a `Column` like this:

```dart
Column(
  children: snapshot.data.map((data) {
    return ListItem(
      data: data,
      user: _user,
    );
  }).toList(),
)
```

Note that I updated the `ListItem` widget to accept the concrete data part instead of a list and an index.

Now you may wonder if the `Column` is less performant than the `ListView.builder`, but it's not. That's because the `ListView.builder` itself didn't scroll, so it didn't layout its children lazily. Rather, the outer `ListView` would decide on whether all of the inner `ListView` should be displayed or not.

**In the long run, you'll probably want to initialize your widgets lazily** (especially if you have users with thousands of pictures). Here's [a StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53729985/flutter-display-content-from-paginated-api-with-dynamic-listview/53841830#53841830) on how to do that with providing multiple `Future`s from a BLoC.

Comment: Very nice explanation, thank you! I tried your solution and it is working, until I scroll up and reach the header part of my page again. It throws following error: "indexOf(child) > index": is not true. Any idea? I googled it, but didnt find anything.

Comment: Solved the issue. It had something to to with the 3 Streambuilders to get the amount of posts, followers and following.

Answer (score 6):

I would not personally use sized components for lists in flutter, only if you want a part of your layout to be scrollable in a specific area.

But in your case, I see that you want the entire page to be scrollable, so you have a starting point, from where you can design the rest of your page. (the entire page should be scrollable, so I understand that the top widget for this page should be a scrollable widget, like SingleChildScrollView, CustomScrollView, ListView etc.)

Now your approach is not wrong, but involves you knowing the final height of the SizedBox, which you can calculate based on your list. (too hard)

To solve your problem, I used a CustomScrollView with SliverList widgets.

```js
return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: <Widget>[
                SliverList(
                  delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                    [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 25.0, top: 30.0),
                        child: Text(displayName,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0)),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                FutureBuilder(
                  future: ApiProvider.getPictures(),
                  builder: ((context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
                        return SliverList(
                            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                                (context, index) => Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                                      child: Column(
                                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Text(
                                            displayName,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                          Text(snapshot.data[index].location),
                                          Image(
                                            image: NetworkImage(snapshot.data[index].pictureUrl),
                                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                                          )
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                childCount: snapshot.data.length));
                      } else {
                        return SliverFillRemaining(
                          child: Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                          ),
                        );
                      }
                    } else {
                      return SliverFillRemaining(
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        ),
                      );
                    }
                  }),
                ),
              ],
            )));
```

There are other solutions to your problem, but I believe that this is the best solution performance wise.

Feel free to ask for help if you need some.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! I went with the solution from Marcel, but could you maybe explain, why you think your solution would be more performant?

Comment: In the second SliverList, you can see that I have used a SliverChildBuilderDelegate, which creates items as they are scrolled onto the screen, similarly to ListView.builder.
I used it as you might have lots of pictures to display, so there is no need to create an image widget if you don't need it.
I personally used code similar to Marcel's solution in my projects, but mapping the list and displaying it in a column might not be the most efficient way, memory and performance wise speaking.